# How to do math operation on rows in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Say, my data file has two columns and five rows as follows,

```
1   3
2   5
3   3
4   4
5   2
```

Now I would like to plot them but with a little math operation on second column. For example,

```
plot 'test.dat' u 1:($2*)
```

What I mean by asterisk is I would like to sqrt(row2^2+row1^2), which is sqrt(5^2+3^2), on second column values. How I can do that? Many thanks!

Comment: Huh? Exactly what are you expecting as a resulting plot? Just a summation of this row and the previous row, or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, one can access only the values of all columns of the current row. Accessing the values of a previous row is possible, but tricky. Basically, you must save the values in temporary variables.

That works in the following way:

1. In the first row, save the values of both columns and do not plot them (use `NaN` as value).
2. In the second row, save the current x-values, use the x-value of the previous row. Then save the current y-value, and compute your value based on the previous row (`prevY`) and the current row (`currY`).

That doesn't plot the last line. But that hasn't a next row anyway. If you want it to plot also the last line with e.g. `0` as additional value, you must add a last row with `0 0`.

In the script I use `set macros` for better readability of the code:

```
set macros
prevX = currX = prevY = currY = 0
UsePreviousXvalue = '(($0 == 0) ? (prevX = NaN, currX = $1) : (prevX = currX, currX = $1)), prevX'
AssignYvalue = '(prevY = currY, currY = $2)'
plot 'test.dat' using (@UsePreviousXvalue):(@AssignYvalue, sqrt(prevY**2 + currY**2))
```

Comment: Y_old =0; plot 'datafilename' using 1:(temp=$2-y_old , y_old=$2 , temp)

Comment: I also got above suggestion but did not work. Posting here in case you could correct it. Thanks for your own answer @Christoph

Comment: That does also work for me (note, that you must have `y_old=0`, with small y!). But that uses the x value of the current and not that of the old value.